# Flow does not enter in the loop

Tags: oracle

Below is a PL/SQL. The problem is that the flow does not enter loop. I am unable to figure out what is the problem. Both the queries return results, i.e the query in the loop and the query within the loop does return results.

```
DECLARE
p_file_name VARCHAR2(4000) :='GHCPExtract_100_005_2011052218000700.csv';
v_file_name  VARCHAR2(4000) :='' || '''' || p_file_name ||'''';
v_count NUMBER :=0;
v_loop        NUMBER :=0;


begin
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'BEFORE LOOP');


FOR C IN (
        SELECT 
S.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT1    ,
S.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT2    ,
S.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT3    ,
S.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT4    ,
S.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT5    ,
S.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT6    
FROM DM_RS.STG_GHCP_EXTRACT S
WHERE S.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = v_file_name

)
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'IN LOOP');
BEGIN

select 
1
into 
v_count
from

(
select 
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT1    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT2    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT3    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT4    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT5    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT6    
from
GTT_SEGMENT_ID t
WHERE 1=1
AND 
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT1 = C.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT1
and
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT2 = C.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT2
and
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT3 = C.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT3
and
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT4 = C.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT4
and
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT5 = C.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT5
and 
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT6 = C.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT6
and t.source_file_name = v_file_name
);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        v_count := 0;
    END;

IF (v_count = 1)
THEN
V_LOOP := V_LOOP +1;
END IF;

END LOOP;

                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( V_LOOP);
   END;
```

DBMS_OUTPUT

BEFORE LOOP

0

Comment: what does `select source_file_name from dm_rs.stg_ghcp_extract where lower(source_file_name) like '%ghcpextract_100_005_2011052218000700.csv%';` return?

Comment: source_file_name. i.e source_file_name is the input parameter like ghcpextract_100_005_2011052218000700.csv

Comment: did you actually run the query I suggested, or are you just guessing? I'm asking, because I would be very surprised if the filename is stored in the table with single quotes around it. Which would explain why your code fails to enter the loop. Also, what is the purpose of this code supposed to be? Is this just a learning exercise, or are you trying to do something with the data returned? Sounds like you're doing a very strange (not to mention slow) way of testing whether a row exists in another table or not. But what will you do with that information once obtained?

Comment: File is stored in ghcpextract_100_005_2011052218000700.csv format and not with single quotes around it. I needed to check that whether or not a segment id of the query in a loop had any matching value in the query inside a loop. And if a match is found then v_loop gets incremented. You are right it is an expensive way to retrieve data but for now its seems the only way.

Comment: It's not the only way - @Stawros has given you an alternative (ie. a single sql statement that uses `EXISTS` - in general, if you're doing nested cursor loops, you should look to combine the queries into one, instead of reinventing table joins yourself!). But what will you be doing with this information once you have it? What does the number give you? P.S. the predicate in your where clause should be amended to: `s.source_file_name = p_file_name` since there are no single quotes stored in the table. No need for the v_file_name variable at all.

Comment: Thank you @Boneist for your advice. I was so hung up with this solution that I did not go for alternates. However I have created a query almost identical to Stawros solution. Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: If you ever use a cursor loop, you should stop and consider whether you can use a single sql statement to do the work (eg. `for rec in (select col1, col2,..) loop insert into .. values (rec.col1, rec.col2, ...); end loop;` should just be `insert into ... select col1, col2, ...`. It's not always possible, of course (eg. writing to a file), but you should at least double-check. If you ever have a nested cursor loop situation, the very minimum that you should do is combine the cursors into one select statement. You improve performance that way, plus the db is designed to handle joins efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v_file_name  VARCHAR2(4000) :='' || '''' || p_file_name ||'''';
....
WHERE S.SOURCE_FILE_NAME =  '' || '''' || v_file_name ||''''
```

How many quotes contain SOURCE_FILE_NAME in table?

You can check count rows in query using temporary variable -

```
SELECT count(1)
 INTO cnt_
 FROM DM_RS.STG_GHCP_EXTRACT S
WHERE S.SOURCE_FILE_NAME =  '''' || v_file_name ||'''';

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('rows count: '||cnt_);
```

Also, check that data in table commited and available in other session.

**EDIT:**

It's obvious that query in cycle returns no rows, because 'IN LOOP' doesn't printed in output.

How many rows return this query? -

```
SELECT count(1)
  FROM dm_rs.stg_ghcp_extract s
 WHERE s.source_file_name = '' || '''' || 'GHCPExtract_100_005_2011052218000700.csv' || ''''
```

Btw, if you need only count of compared rows you can use one select with `EXISTS` instead of cycle.

```
SELECT count(1)
  into v_count
  FROM dm_rs.stg_ghcp_extract c
 WHERE c.source_file_name = v_file_name
   AND EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM gtt_segment_id t
            WHERE t.source_trx_key_segment1 = c.source_trx_key_segment1
              AND t.source_trx_key_segment2 = c.source_trx_key_segment2
              AND t.source_trx_key_segment3 = c.source_trx_key_segment3
              AND t.source_trx_key_segment4 = c.source_trx_key_segment4
              AND t.source_trx_key_segment5 = c.source_trx_key_segment5
              AND t.source_trx_key_segment6 = c.source_trx_key_segment6
              AND t.source_file_name = c.source_file_name)
```

Comment: Only two. Sorry for the inconvenience. I have corrected my question. And I need values from the loop in order to compare them with the values T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT1    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT2    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT3    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT4    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT5    ,
T.SOURCE_TRX_KEY_SEGMENT6  of the query within the loop. If a match is found then select will return as 1 and 1 will be stored in v_count which is used in IF condition within the loop

Comment: Thank you for your time and advice. :)